# Is it needed to include the hints for java lint with Typescript , VS - 2013

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, typescript

My files all look like this with the jslint part at the top:

```
/*global angular*/

   angular.module('xx')
    .controller('XController', [
        '$http',

        xController
   ]);
```

As I convert to Typescript do I even need to have the /*global angular*/ definitions there. Also do I need to turn off the lint checking somehow with VS2013 Udpate 2 onwards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I convert to Typescript do I even need to have the /global angular/ definitions there

No. TypeScript uses definitions files. e.g for angular https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts

You simply reference it like the following

```
/// <reference path="angular.d.ts" />
```

## More

You get *much greater typesafety* than a simple saying the `angular` is global, which you can still do with typescript as simple as :

```
declare var angular:any;
```

Answer (score 2):

JSLint is for javascript, not typescript. It's not going to be able to parse your code unless you never use any features from typescript (thus defeating the point).